# unable to write contents to a file

Tags: javascript, titanium

```
  var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, 'properties.txt');
  var writeStream = Titanium.Filesystem.getFileStream(f);
  writeStream.open(Titanium.Filesystem.MODE_WRITE);
  writeStream.write("this is the new file");
  writeStream.close();
```

I am getting an error " **Cannot find function getFileStream in object** "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.3/Titanium.Filesystem-module

Titanium.Filesystem.getFile returns you a Titanium.Filesystem.File object which you are setting to the variable f

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.Filesystem.File.open-method.html

EDIT: You could try commenting out your first line entirely.  Feed the full path to getFileStream and that could show if its getFile thats causing the problems.

Save a test file under root (C:) and try

```
var writeStream = Titanium.Filesystem.getFileStream("C:\test.txt");
writeStream.open(MODE_WRITE);
writeStream.write("perhaps this will work");
writeStream.close();
```

Comment: Both of them are giving me errors, your code and my code too... it does not rec the open method now.

Comment: hmm, I cant actually see an obvious error, try feeding getFileStream a complete path to see if its getFile thats messing up

Comment: edited the code snippet above, bypassing the getFile method call will at least show whether its your first or second line thats going wrong

Comment: But i am actually doing it mobile device... its no desktop

Comment: Yet again i am getting the same error " Cannot find function getFileStream in object "